# Running the exploration result file of the TestSuite machine(Spec Explorer) in a Console Application

Tags: testing, console-application, spec#

I'm having a problem while trying to follow a example of Spec Explorer, while using Visual Studio 2012.
I've been following this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/specexplorer/archive/2009/11/24/using-the-exploration-result-object-model-basics.aspx), but I get stuck on the running the Spec Explorer file with a Console Application.

My problem starts at the next sentence:
"Running this part of the program on the exploration result file of the TestSuite machine in the SMB2 project results in output as below:"

I don't know how to do this, but they don't elaborate on it, does anyone of you know how I should do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Visual Studio (VS)2012.
Then I guess you tried already the "RequirementReport" example of Spec Explorer.
This should give you the same possibilities and a running example (using VS2010).
I assume you tried this example, but it was not working (due to VS2012).
Then you tried it with this article in your link.

You're interested in just a report of an exploration result. You're not playing with the idea any  more of creating your own full blown path coverage strategy. Right?

You created a new console-application-C#-project and copied the program code from the end of the article into it.
You are able to compile. But you forgot to replace "args[0]" with the full qualified path to an .seexpl-file! Right?

A lot of guessing, but I need 4 more points until I can ask questions in a comment ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use VS2012, I indeed tried the RequirementReport, and it didn't work due to VS2012.
I'm just trying to understand Spec Explorer better. The full blown path coverage strategy was also one of the things I tried, but isn't what I'm doing here.
I feel like a newb now, but I can't seem to find the .seexpl file, so I guess that's the problem.

Comment: @Kyra
Please try this: 
Open the "Chat"-Example in VS. (SMB2 is very advanced with many detailed features, so go for it later)
In the Exploration Manager go on "TestSuite" and explore this machine.

Comment: Now you should find the file "C:\Users\kyra\Documents\Spec Explorer 2010\Samples\chat\Model\ExplorationResults\TestSuite.seexpl"
It contains the complete serialized exploration and this example contains also requirment-tags, which you can now search with the tool in the article.
Please note that I'm still on VS2010 here and can't really follow all problems now. At some point you might need help from microsoft directly (VS2012 issues).
Do you get further with this?

Comment: I've found it now, thank you. It's not working yet, but I'm atleast a step further. Thank you for your help.